# javascript new 2D array not being created inspite of using .map

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I wanted to generate new two-dimensional arrays from a existing 2D array and then change the value of some elements of the new array but whenever I try to modify the array content it is showing changes to all the generated arrays (which means they all have the same reference).Please ,help me to find my error and provide relevant methods and concepts to create the new 2D arrays

Another question is why the testing for loop returns "No error" while they are still equal
I am still a beginner in javascript.So any help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance

My Code is at http://jsbin.com/miqapupopa/edit?js,console

This is my code:

```
var a=[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];var big_arr=[a];var c=-1;
//function f(){this.objarr = a.map(function(val){return val;}) ;};
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
    var arr=a.map(function(val){return val;}) ;
    if(a[i][j]===0){
      arr[i][j]=c;
      big_arr.push(arr);}
     continue;
  }  c=(c===1)?-1:1;console.log(c);
}console.log(big_arr,a);
for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
  console.log(big_arr[i]);
}
//just checking if all arrays are equal
for(var k=0;k<9;k++){
if(big_arr[k]==a) console.log("error"); //toString works
  else console.log("No error");}
//output should be obj=[[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[-1,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[0,-1,0],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[0,0,-1],[0,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]],[[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]][[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,1]]]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK to clone an N dimensional array let's invent a generic Array method. `Array.prototype.clone()`

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p),[])
}

var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    brr = arr.clone();
brr[0][1] = 11;
brr[2][2] = 55;
arr[1][1] = 42;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
console.log(JSON.stringify(brr));
```

The above code is utilizing reduce method to generate a clone of a multi-dimensional array. It is a recursive function. In this example reduce takes two arguments. 1) A a callback function 2) An initial parameter.

**Callback function:** `(p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p)` is actually

```
function(p,c,i) {
  if (Array.isArray(c)) {
    p[i] = c.clone(); // recursive cloning call with inner array item
  } else {
    p[i] = c;
  }
  return p;
}
```

**Initial Parameter:** An initial value provided for `p` to start with. In this case it is an empty array (`[]`).

Actually in the comments Thomas has given a `map` version of the very same code. You may chose to use that one too.

And then if you would like to instantiate an ND array from scratch and fill it witn an initial value you will definitelly need the above cloning utility. Lets do...

```js
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p),[])
}

function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = (new Array(c)).fill(true).map(e => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone() : p ));
}

var arr = arrayND(...[6,6,6],8); //last argument is the initializing value
arr[1][3][5] = "eight";
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: please don't extend basic types, this leads to very dark places and little kittens will have to die. Better u create a utility-function. 2nd why reduce()? why not just plain map()?  sth. like this: `function cloneArray(v){ return Array.isArray(v)? v.map(cloneArray): v; }`

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your comment. However i have to say I totally disagree with the general JS community on extending the basic types. The prototypical structure is our friend and there is no real reason for not to utilize it. People just keep saying that just like them having no idea about Haskell but adore it deeply. I believe utility functions are imperative approaches. A functional approach takes a chain-able sequential programming paradigm and Array.prototype.reduce() is such a fantastic tool that i use it for like almost 80-85% of my array operations.

Comment: A reason to not extend basic types is, that two people may get the idea to extend the same property on the same type with two functions that do slightly different things. It's not like it never happened to me. Then methods are not that easy to compose; when talking about FP. Especially not in JS where you have to take care of the scope. And to the last point: reduce() is a great tool, agree. But you're basically (re-)implementing map() by using reduce(), and that makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Thomas I actually liked your map approach on clone. And yes you are right with your feelings. I am not reducing anything here am i.. ? It's just that reduce is in fact map on steroids comes at no cost. I love the idea of reduce being self contained with all the initial parameter and all which also applies to map as well. Well they are both cool tools. When it comes to prototype usage. In production code yes... one should be very careful.

Comment: @Redu Ok ,so this code opens the door to es6 for me but I still want to know why were all the new arrays referencing the same array .I thought map itself created new array.
Also ,I want to know that when I was checking whether all the arrays were equal(which they were) it returned that they aren't
Also, in your code ,I'm unable to understand
   
`  return this.reduce((p,c,i) => (p[i] = Array.isArray(c) ? c.clone() : c, p),[])`

what is `, p`doing ?
Also,I am working on understanding your second code and will ask you if any doubt.

Comment: @Utkarsh Shukla The problem in you code is a common misunderstanding of array cloning. The line `arr = a.map(function(val){return val;})` is essentially the same as `arr = a.slice()`. They both return  a different array called `arr` (`a == arr // false`) however the items of `a` and `arr` keep referenceing each other i.e. `a[0] == arr[0] // true` Neither map nor slice could create a deeply nested clones. It's not their job. As per my code, I will edit my answer to include an explanation in detail.

Comment: @Redu Thanks to you ,I am able to understand what my mistake was. I was pushing the nested array and all those were just being referenced to the same array and not copied . Also ,now I understand your both functions and able to make their equivalent es5 functions .I really liked your one-liners . One more point though ,I think new keyword isn't really needed in the second function .Once again ,thanks for your fast replies.

Comment: @Thomas I tried your technique too .It was also quite helpful and easy to understand .Thanks!.